# How to extract jira ticket number with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to extract Jira ticket number from the branch name with sed.
This is what I have

`echo "PTW-123-branch-name" | sed 's/.*\([A-Z]+-[0-9]+[^-]\).*/\1/'`

expected result: `PTW-123`

What is wrong with the regexp?

Comment: As for what's wrong, plain `sed` does not support `+` repetition. Try `\+` or see if your `sed` supports an `-E` or `-r` flag to switch to a less basic regex dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
echo "PTW-123-branch-name" | sed 's/\([0-9]\)-.*$/\1/'

PTW-123
```

**Details:**

- `\([0-9]\)-`: Matches a digit and captures it in group #1 followed by hyphen
- `.*$`: Match remaining string until end
- `\1`: Is replacement that puts captured digit back in output

Alternatively you can use `cut` also:

```sh
echo "PTW-123-branch-name" | cut -d- -f1,2

PTW-123
```

Comment: This is useful to extract the ticket number only with a string as in the example. I am trying to find a general regex to extract any ticket number. I have tried with `local issueName="$(echo "$string" | sed -e 's/feature\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/bugfix\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/hotfix\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/release\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/')"` but sometimes it breaks and brings extra strings. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @MrEduar: Your problem appears different, please post a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846574/how-to-extract-jira-issue-ticket-in-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with `GNU grep` please try following then. Simple explanation would be passing `echo` command's output as a standard input to `grep` command. Then in `grep` command using `-oP` option to print only matched portion and enabling PCRE regex capabilities here. In match section of `grep` then using non-greedy match to match till digits which should be followed by `-`, then if a match is found it will print it.

```
echo "PTW-123-branch-name"  | grep -oP '^.*?\d+(?=-)'
```