# How to extract jira issue ticket in bash script?

Tags: bash, git, sed, grep, jira

I am trying to atomatize my git commits with bash functions so that they add a text before each commit if they detect that they are on a branch with a jira ticket.

For example
I am working on a new issue and the branch is called
`bugfix/MR2-71-sidebar-modification`
where `MR2-71` is the jira ticket number. I would like to find a general way to find as many cases as possible.

The bash functions I have are as follows

```sh
function getIssueName() {
    local string="$(git branch --no-color | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')"

    # Extract the issue name from the branch name with regex without perl
    # For example extract MR2-16 of the string feature/MR2-16-requests-list
    # string variable will be feature/MR2-16-requests-list
    # issueName variable will be MR2-123 only
    local issueName="$(echo "$string" | sed -e 's/feature\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/bugfix\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/hotfix\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/release\/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' -e 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/')"

    # if issueName is empty or equal to string then return empty
    if [ -z "$issueName" ] || [ "$issueName" = "$string" ]; then
        echo ""
    else
        echo "$issueName"
    fi
}
```

but `issueName` variable does not seem to have the ticket number correctly, as it sometimes brings extra string.
for example `MR2-71-sidebar-mod` or `MR2-75-table`

Example content of the `string` variable (one for each line):

```
bugfix/MR2-38-refactor-routes-for-requests-list
bugfix/MR2-39-default-sorting-order-in-requests-list
feature/MR2-17-feature-clients-list
feature/MR2-34-laravel-9-upgrade
```

Example of the result that the function `getIssueName` should return (one for each line):

```
MR2-38
MR2-39
MR2-17
MR2-34
```

Any idea how to extract the issue number and make the function work in any case?

For example something like `[aA-zZZ]-[0-9]` (sorry I know almost nothing about regex)

Comment: What is the rule, in English, for the format of Jira ticket numbers? We can't write code to detect them without knowing that.

Comment: Currently it would be `MR2-incremental-number-here`

Comment: Please add sample output of `git branch --no-color` command and your expected output from above function

Comment: I have added a few examples @anubhava

Comment: The pattern for "MR2-incremental-number-here" would be `/MR2-\d+/`.

Comment: @AndyLester How would it be applied with sed? You can leave your full answer below if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's|[^/]*/\([^-]*-[^-]*\).*|\1|' <<< "$string"
MR2-38
MR2-39
MR2-17
MR2-34
```

Answer (score 2):

A project key is capital letters and numbers (I assume it has to start with a letter), so you might want

```
grep -E -o '[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+'
```

Demo:

```sh
strings=(
    bugfix/MR2-38-refactor-routes-for-requests-list
    bugfix/MR2-39-default-sorting-order-in-requests-list
    feature/MR2-17-feature-clients-list
    feature/MR2-34-laravel-9-upgrade
)
for string in "${strings[@]}"; do
  grep -Eo '[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+' <<< "$string"
done
```

```
MR2-38
MR2-39
MR2-17
MR2-34
```

We can do this with just bash as well

```sh
if [[ $string =~ ([A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+) ]]; then
  issue=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "no issue number found in string '$string'" >&2
fi
echo $issue   # => MR2-34
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a function for this. It may not be the prettiest / most idomatic bash, but it does work for a decent amount of cases.

One caveat - this function doesn't exit non-zero if a ticket ID doesn't exist. It's designed to pull from the branch name, and lays out some assumptions on where the ticket would be. It does not matter what case the ticket ID is in, or whether it contains numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# function to extract ticket id from branch name
function extract_ticket_id() {
  # handles extraction for branches that contain a forward slash
  # example: feat/TICKET-200-other-desciptors -> TICKET-200
  if [[ $1 == *"/"* ]]; then
    {
      echo "$1" | cut -d/ -f 2 | cut -d- -f 1,2
    }

  # handles ticket extraction from commitizen syntax (assumes ticket number is subject)
  # example: feat(TICKET-ID): add thing
  elif [[ $1 == *"("* ]]; then
  {
    echo "$1" | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1
  }
  # handles cases where branches use dashes to delimit terms
  # example: TICKET-200-other-desciptors -> TIC-200
  elif [[ $1 == *"-"* ]]; then
  {
    echo "$1" | cut -d- -f 1,2
  }

  fi
}

export -f extract_ticket_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed:

```sh
getIssueName() {
   git branch --no-color | sed -E 's~^[^/]+/([^-]+-[^-]+).*~\1~'
}
```

**Example:**

```sh
cat file

bugfix/MR2-38-refactor-routes-for-requests-list
bugfix/MR2-39-default-sorting-order-in-requests-list
feature/MR2-17-feature-clients-list
feature/MR2-34-laravel-9-upgrade

sed -E 's~^[^/]+/([^-]+-[^-]+).*~\1~' file

MR2-38
MR2-39
MR2-17
MR2-34
```

Comment: This brings me all the branches in my repo, I only want one. That is to say
getIssueName should only return `MR2-38` or `MR2-39` or `MR2-17`, but never all 3, I just need to identify the issueName in the branch I am currently in.

Comment: Now it returns 1, its ok, but it returns the full name of the branch. It should return only the issue name. It is also returning the first branch it finds, and it should be the current branch.

Comment: But then your output does not show current branch marker

Comment: See updated. But you need to provide full output of `git branch --no-color` with your **exact** expected output. If you expected only one output why did you show 4 output lines?

Comment: I clarify that it is one for each line, 1 input 1 output. I have tried your latest update, but it still gives me the full branch name. `local string="$(git branch --no-color | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')"` output `bugfix/MR2-52-drag-and-drop-to-re-order-statuses` Then, I want to apply changes so that I am left with `MR2-52`

Comment: Isn't the accepted answer same as my original answer shown here?